# Remove preferences and application support files from already uninstalled apps

Tags: macos

I want to remove preferences and application support files from already uninstalled apps.  I have app cleaner to remove those files when I delete the application, but that only works for stuff after I installed App Cleaner.  Any automated system for programs removed before I installed App Cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [CleanMyMac 2](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac)

CleanMyMac 2 has an Uninstaller feature that includes the ability to remove leftovers from uninstalled applications.

> **No more Leftovers**
>   If you used to uninstall applications by dragging them to Trash, then you have tons of apps leftovers! Find and remove them using CleanMyMac2.

[image: Uninstaller → Leftovers]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!